# KeyedCollection and d:DataContext Design Error

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013, datacontext, design-time

See the update below for VS2013.

When using a class as a `d:DesignInstance` that exposes a `KeyedCollection<TKey, TItem>`, the XAML designer complains with the following warning:

> The number of generic arguments provided doesn't equal the arity of
>   the generic type definition.
>
> Parameter name: instantiation

The problem can be reproduced with the following simple program:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
        mc:Ignorable="d"  
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MyClass}" />

namespace Test
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow() { InitializeComponent(); }
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        public KeyedCollection<string, object> SettingsModule { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

I'm unable to provide design time shape with any class that exposes a `KeyedCollection`.

Any ideas what is going on here?

---

Update: As of VS2013 the behavior of the designer in dealing with a `KeyedCollection` has changed (though still not fully working).

The above example no longer generates an error.  However, if the `KeyedCollection` uses certain types (such as an interface) as the `TItem` the following error is generated:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Consider the following example:

```
namespace Test
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow() { InitializeComponent(); }
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        public KeyedCollection<string, IInterface> MyCollection { get; private set; }
    }

    public interface IInterface
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've been able to resolve this issue by prefixing the design instance type with "d:Type" as such:

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance d:Type=local:MyClass}"
```

This seems to be a bug in the VS2013 designer. I believe the d:Type property should be the default property of the `d:DesignInstance` attribute. Also, strangely I've only seen this issue with the `KeyedCollection` class.

Furthermore, the [MSDN examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602277%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) of `d:DesignInstance` usage sometimes use "Type" with no prefix.  In this example if `d:Type` is omitted or the prefix is missing, the design time error is generated as I mentioned.

Comment: Seems to exist in VS2015 as well

Answer (score 0):

If I have'nt misunderstood your question try it like

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Width="800" Height="800"
    Title="MainWindow"   
    >
<Window.DataContext>
    **<local:MyClass />**
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
</Grid>
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't quite address my particular issue.  I specifically need to use the d:DataContext to supply design time data shape in the XAML designer.  I set the actual DataContext in a different way.

See here for more on design time data:
http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2009/10/28/ddesigninstance-ddesigndata-in-visual-studio-2010-beta2/

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the Default Constructor from my DesignInstance-Class